# Dockerfile support multiple from

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I have a need to run python on different CPU architectures such as AMD64 and ARM (Raspberry Pi) etc.  I read the documentation from Docker that Multi Stage Build is probably the way to go.

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
LABEL MAINTAINER=XXX
ADD speedtest-influxdb.py /speedtest/speedtest-influxdb.py

ENV INFLUXDB_SERVER="http://10.88.88.10:49161"

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN python3 -m pip install 'influxdb-client[ciso]'
RUN python3 -m pip install speedtest-cli

CMD python3 /speedtest/speedtest-influxdb.py

FROM arm32v7/python:3.10-slim
LABEL MAINTAINER=XXX
ADD speedtest-influxdb.py /speedtest/speedtest-influxdb.py

ENV INFLUXDB_SERVER="http://10.88.88.10:49161"

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN python3 -m pip install 'influxdb-client[ciso]'
RUN python3 -m pip install speedtest-cli

CMD python3 /speedtest/speedtest-influxdb.py
```

But as you can see there's a bit to repetition.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If you used a multistage build like this, doesn't it throw away everything from before the second FROM? How do you run this/tag the image?

Comment: @NickODell Actually im new to docker and havent got to that stage to test yet.  However you are right, i would like lto reuse as much as i can from 1st stage by "copying"

Comment: Ah, that explains why it failed to build on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical use of a multi-stage build is to build some artifact you want to run or deploy, then `COPY` it into a final image that doesn't include the build tools.  It's not usually the right tool when you want to build several separate things, or several variations on the same thing.

In your case, all of the images are identical except for the `FROM` line.  You can use an `ARG` to specify the image you're building `FROM` ([in this specific case](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) `ARG` comes before `FROM`)

```bash
ARG base_image=python:3.10-slim
FROM ${base_image}
...
CMD ["/speedtest/speedtest.py"]
# but only once
```

If you just `docker build` this image, you'll get the default `base_image`, which will use a default Python for the current default architecture.  But you can request a different base image, or a different target platform

```bash
# Use the ARM32-specific image
docker build --build-arg base_image=arm32v7/python:3.10-slim .

# Force an x86 image (with emulation if supported)
docker build --platform linux/amd64 .
```

Comment: How would you handle the tags for the same version but different CPU?  Or would you simple use tags e.g speedtest:1.0.0-amd64 and speedtest:1.0.0-arm32